# Publisher name does not appear in a technical report bibliography entry in ACM format

Tags: bibliographies, acm, acmart

I use ACM format teamplate. I have this entry in my bib file:

```
@techreport{me15,
    author = {Last, First},
    title = {On Testing},
    type = {Final Resport},
    publisher  = {A University},
    year = {2015},
}
```

What I get in the references section in the PDF is:

```
First Last. 2015. On Testing. Final Report.
```

I need to show the publisher name int he references in the PDF. What should I change in my entry?

Comment: Try `institution` instead.

Answer (score 1):

@koleygr is right - institution will make it work.

Otherwise, if you want to keep it in publisher, and you're allowed to modify the bst file, you can change the techreport section to:

```
FUNCTION { techreport }
{
  output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output             % added
  output.year.check                    % added
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
%   format.tr.number output               % jtb: moved month ...
  format.tr.number output new.sentence    % Gerry  - need dot 2011/09/28
  institution "institution" bibinfo.output.check
  publisher "publisher" bibinfo.output.check %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% this is the new bit
  address empty.or.unknown
    { }
    { "\bibinfo{address}{" address "}" * * output }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.named.pages output
  % ACM omits year at end in transactions style
  % format.day.month.year output.nonnull.dot.space  % jtb: ... to here (no parens)
  fin.block
  output.issue.doi.coden.isxn.lccn.url.eprint.note
  fin.entry
}
```

[image: screengrab showing ref working]

Overleaf link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jzskbdnfqxpd